# Equivalent parametric plots don't look the same

Tags: plotting

```
ParametricPlot[ {1, Tan[t]}, {t, -Pi/3, Pi/3}]
ParametricPlot[ Sec[t] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi/3, Pi/3}]
```

The second parametrization does not plot like the first, how to make it plot without changing its form?

Comment: use `Evaluate` in the second line:, i.e, `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Sec[t] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}], {t, -Pi/3, Pi/3}]`. Or  `Evaluated->True`, i.e., `ParametricPlot[Sec[t] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi/3, Pi/3}, 
 Evaluated -> True]`

Comment: Or include `PlotRange -> {{-.1, 2.1}, {-1.9, 1.9}}`

Comment: Thanks. Expected the plot defaults would automatically handle simple cases.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variant on Bob Hanlon's comment -- just for the record.

```
 ParametricPlot[Sec[t] {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, -Pi/3, Pi/3},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, Automatic}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: ParametricPlot[ {1, Tan[t]}, {t, -Pi/3, Pi/3}]              when plots directly ok , why do the rest need extra Range specification?

Comment: @Narasimham. The heuristics _Mathematica_ uses for choosing plot range when none is specified are unknown to me. But giving the option `PlotRange` to manually override the automatic choice will always solve the kind of problem you have encountered.